# Node console.log behavior and windows stdout

Tags: windows, node.js, powershell

I've noticed strange behavior when trying to redirect the output form a node.js script in Windows. The smallest reproducible example of this behavior is as follows:

From the Windows console (cmd.exe):

```
c:\> node -e console.log('hello')
hello
```

From Powershell:

```
PS C:\> node -e console.log('hello')
PS C:\>
```

That is to say, it exits without writing anything to the console.

This is a problem because when I try to redirect the output to a file, nothing is written, eg

```
node -e console.log(123) > temp.txt
```

is creating an empty file named temp.txt.

Is there something about how node is writing console.out to stdio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the problem is in the parenthesis.

Try this:

```
node -e "console.log('hello')"
```

As for the redirection, there is imho ne reason why this should not work. You may also try to pipe it to `Out-File temp.txt`.

Comment: ah - that helps with the example of running it from the command line, (thanks!) but I'm still getting empty files when redirecting the output from a script file, eg "node script.js > log.txt". This is blank from Powershell, but as expected from cmd.exe. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm accepting this as an answer because it worked great on another machine. I was never able to get it working on my original machine, so I suspect I have some other weirdness going on. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you "dot" your call to "node" when calling from PowerShell?

```
.\node -e "console.log('hello')" >test2.txt
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and after banging my head against the wall, I un-installed 32-bit node (from my 64-bit machine) and installed 64-bit node. Now I get Node output in my Powershell scripts.
Don't know whether it was fixed by the reinstall, or the 64- vs 32- bitness.